# Using variables from imported file giving a NameError, even though 'global' has been used

Tags: python, variables, import, nameerror

I am designing a program that simulates a Turing machine, with the rules in a separate file for easy editing. Unfortunately, it throws up a NameError when it first tries to compute from the ruleTable.

The offending snippet:

```
import TheRules

def turIt():
    global ruleTable #Global has been used here.
    tapeSegment = tape[tapePos]
    for x in range(0,len(ruleTable)): #Error here.
        if ruleTable[x][2] == machineState and ruleTable[x][3] == tape[tapePos]:
            machineState = ruleTable[x][4]
            tape[tapePos] = ruleTable[x][5]
            move(ruleTable[x][6])
```

TheRules:

```
ruleTable = [1]
ruleTable[0] = ("startRule","anyVal","anyVal","1","1",1)
#New rules go down here:
```

To be precise: "NameError: Global name 'ruleTable' is not defined"

What would be the easiest way to deal with this? I am thoroughly confused by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import TheRules` only loads `TheRules` module into local namesapce, not its contents (varaibles, functions, ...).

Use `from TheRules import ruleTable` to load `ruleTable` to local namespace.

Or access the variable using `TheRules.ruleTable`

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the answer.

Comment: Not that you should ever do it, but for the sake of completion you can also do `from Therules import *` to import all the names at once. It gets confusing quickly though.